# Как настроить SelectedItem

Tags: wpf

Приложение представляет собой конструктор тестов, данное окно находиться только на начальной стадии разработки в тестовом решении. Проблема заключается в том что при создании нескольких вопросов, их можно выбрать мышкой, затем выбрать редактируемый элемент и изменить его например поле Text в классе CheckedItem, тогда все будет работать корректно и элемент в коллекции измениться, но если выбрать в другом вопросе его элемент не кликнув сначала на сам вопрос и после на его элемент и изменить его, изменения не будут учтены, так как не изменилось поле private Question selectedControlQuestion в классе MainWindowViewModel, изменить его в классе Question не представляется возможным. Данный функционал нужен для редактирования определенных элементов в приложении пользователем. Я только недавно начал изучать wpf, поэтому мог выбрать неправильный подход для выполнения данной задачи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckedItemSelector" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextItemSelector">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <vm:QuestionsDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding interfaceElements}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
                SelectedControlQuestion}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding NameQuestion, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedControlItem}" 
                                     ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}">
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Create" Content="Создать вопрос" Width="150" 
                Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateQuestion}"/>
        <Button x:Name="CreateText" Content="Добавить текстовое поле" Width="150" 
                Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateText}"/>
        <Button x:Name="CreateCheck" Content="Добавить CheckBox" Width="150" 
                Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"
                Command ="{Binding CreateChekc}"/>
    </Grid>`введите сюда код`
```

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Question> interfaceElements { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

        private Question selectedControlQuestion;
        public Question SelectedControlQuestion
        {
            get { return selectedControlQuestion; }
            set
            {
                selectedControlQuestion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedControlQuestion");
            }
        }

        public ICommand CreateQuestion { get; }
        private void OnCreateQuestionExecuted(object parameters)
        {
            var question = new Question() { NameQuestion = "Введите заголовок ответа"};
            interfaceElements.Add(question);
            SelectedControlQuestion = question;
        }
        private bool CanCreateQuestionExecuted(object parameter) => true;

        public ICommand CreateText { get; }
        private void OnCreateTextExecuted(object parameters)
        {
        var question = new TextItem() { Text = "Введите ответ" };
            selectedControlQuestion.Items.Add(question);
        }
        private bool CanCreateTextExecuted(object parameter) => true;

        public ICommand CreateChekc { get; }
        private void OnCreateChekcExecuted(object parameters)
        {
            var question = new CheckedItem() { Text = "Введите вопрос" };
            selectedControlQuestion.Items.Add(question);
        }
        private bool CanCreateChekcExecuted(object parameter) => true;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            CreateQuestion = new LambdaCommand(OnCreateQuestionExecuted, CanCreateQuestionExecuted);
            CreateText = new LambdaCommand(OnCreateTextExecuted, CanCreateTextExecuted);
            CreateChekc = new LambdaCommand(OnCreateChekcExecuted, CanCreateChekcExecuted);
        }
```

```
public class Question : ViewModel
    {
        private string nameQuestion;
        public string NameQuestion
        {
            get { return nameQuestion; }
            set
            {
                nameQuestion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NameQuestion");
            }
        }

        private IQuestionItem selectedControlItem;
        public IQuestionItem SelectedControlItem
        {
            get { return selectedControlItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedControlItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedControlItem");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IQuestionItem> Items { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<IQuestionItem>();
    }
```

```
public class CheckedItem : ViewModel, IQuestionItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        private bool correctAnswer = false;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get { return correctAnswer; }
            set
            {
                correctAnswer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CorrectAnswer");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class TextItem : ViewModel, IQuestionItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Мне кажется у вас не правильный подход к созданию тестов, не в плане кода, а в плане самой логики составления. Вот есть вопрос, например "Сколько яблок будет?", ответ на него число, то есть нужно поле для ввода. Может у этого вопроса быть чекбокс, или что-то еще? Нет. Или вот вопрос "Выберите правильный ответ из предложенных" - это у нас список чекбоксов. Может тут быть текстовое поле? Нет. Исходя из этой логики, у нас формируется вопрос, с одним типом ответа (чекбокс, радиобаттн, текст. поле, др.), а это значит, что ваши кнопки "добавить" не в тему)

Comment: Касательно вопроса, тут тоже мне кажется ваша логика не очень правильная. Вы отталкиваетесь от выделенного элемента, когда как "добавить" должно быть у каждого вопроса в конце, а напротив каждого элемента кнопка "удалить".

Comment: Это тестовый вариант для проверки работы приложения. Я понимаю что сейчас элементы добавляться некорректно согласно логики, сейчас мне важнее сделать корректное редактирование выбранного элемента после я займусь правильным добавлением элементов, но это не изменит мою проблему в плане выбора элементы для редактирования. Я стремлюсь к этому варианту конструктора теста: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1VU6eXRlqIVNjTf-1sxpUGcRKqAX7TcjCTa3kbCY0BLk/edit

Comment: Ну посмотрите внимательней на гугл формы, вы указываете тип вопросу, ваш вопрос не может состоять сразу и из чекбоксов, и из текстовых полей, он имеет один конкретный тип. В вашей текущей логике ваш вопрос не вопрос, а просто каша из контролов, где может и что-то выбрать, и что-то написать. `то не изменит мою проблему в плане выбора элементы для редактирования` - почему это? Опять смотрим на гугл формы, где там добавление нового элемента в вопрос? Где-то за пределами вопроса, или внутри самого вопроса поле "добавить"? Вам не нужно тут вообще выделение, и не нужен `ListBox`.

Comment: Дело в том что я не могу понять как мне изменить подход. Вот к примеру, я буду добавлять в тест вопросы и их может быть множество и мне их нужно где-то хранить, для этого была использована коллекция, сам вопрос может хранить в зависимости от выбора пользователя текстовое поле и чекбокс в итоге нужно 2 коллекции для самих вопросов и их элементов так как вопросов может быть множество и их элементов тоже и оба они создают тест, и проблема в редактировании возникает из-за вложенных коллекций. Если вы знаете как можно это сделать по другому, можете кратко описать я буду вам благодарен.

Comment: Я вам уже говорил как надо... Забудьте про UI, забудьте про кнопки, поля, чекбоксы, вот представьте, что у вас консольный проект, и вам надо классами описать всю структуру ваших вопросов. Как сделаете? Вот у вас есть условно 3 вида вопросов: 1. Человек сам пишет ответ. 2. Человек выбирает несколько из предложенных. 3. Человек выбирает один из предложенных. У каждого вопроса общее что? Сам вопрос, описание, варианты, ответ. Вот и сделайте такой интерфейс, который будет в себе это содержать, ответ и варианты пусть будут генерик. Ну а дальше, сделайте классы под разные типы, реализующие интерфейс